# Ruby on Rails, display the name(typ in model) of category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my projekt i have two models, an "Treatment"-Model and a "Category"-Model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :typ
has_many :treatments
end  

class Treatment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :patient
belongs_to :category
attr_accessible :content, :day, :typ, :category_typ
end
```

So in my treatment form the user can also choose the category:

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :category_id %><br />
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.find(:all), :id, :typ %>
</div>
```

My problem is that later i can display the category_id but i really dont know how i can display the catogory typ:

```
<% @patient.treatments.each do |treatment| %>
<tr>
<td><%= treatment.category_id %></td>
<td><%= treatment.content %></td>
<td><%= treatment.day %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

I tried category_typ, but didnt worked! Im beginner in rails and i hope somebody can help me! Thanks!

```
def show
@patient = Patient.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @patient }
end
end
```

Comment: Try this: `treatment.category.try(:typ)` If category is not nil, it will display its attribute `:typ`

Comment: Do you know a site where .try is explaind? Somehow i never came in contact with it it?

Comment: You can find documentation here: http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works with

```
  <td><%= treatment.category && treatment.category.typ %></td>
```

because category is nil for some treatment objects. If treatments need to have a category I would put a validation on the model level as well as a foreign key restrction on the database.

```
  class Treatment
    validates_presence_of :treatment
  end
```

and then in a migration

```
  remove_column :treatments, :category_id
  add_column :treatments, :category_id, :null => false
```

this will ensure referential integrity in your database. if the relationship is not required then ignore this. You can also make your code 1 method call by using .try

```
 <td><%= treatment.category.try(:typ)%></td>
```

Comment: Because you mentioned validation, i have another question, that refers on validation. Maybe you can help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136314/ruby-on-rails-is-it-possible-to-make-the-model-validation-dependent-on-the-inpu

Answer (score 1):

You use `treatment.category.typ`.

You also need `@patient = Patient.where(:id => params[:id]).includes(:treatment => [:category]).first` in your controller.

Comment: didnt worked, i get the error undefined method `typ' for nil:NilClass

Comment: You should include category in your query.

Comment: how? Sorry im new to rails!

Comment: Can you show me the code where you assign to @patient? (from the controller)

Comment: oh i didnt assign anything to the controller, i updatet my question with the def show in the controller

Comment: Try @patient = Patient.where(:id => params[:id]).includes(:treatment => [:category]).first

Comment: @EmSta That queries the category and displays the type. But it is performing lazy loading, so if you want better performance, you should go with the query string above.

Comment: you mean i should use treatment.category.try(:typ)?

Comment: No, I mean you should preload your categories like this @patient = Patient.where(:id => params[:id]).includes(:treatment => [:category]).first

Answer (score 1):

Ok somehow it works with

```
<td><%= treatment.category && treatment.category.typ %></td>,
```

maybe someone knows why this works?