# Ruby on Rails, is it possible to make the model validation dependent on the input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my project I have two models, `Treatment` and `Category`:

```
 class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :typ
   has_many :treatments
 end  

 class Treatment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :patient
   belongs_to :category
   attr_accessible :content, :day, :typ, :category_typ
 end
```

So in my treatment form the user can also choose the category (around 4 categories):

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :category_id %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.find(:all), :id, :typ %>
</div>
```

So my question is, can I make the validation of the `Treatment` model dependent on the selected categories in the form? And how?

Comment: I see a possible problem with your associations. If you want be able to select several categories for every `Treatment`, than `Treatment` should have `has_many :categories` association.

Comment: no it only has to have one treatment! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
validate :something_based_on_category

def something_based_on_category
  if self.category==.....
end
```

You also use `errors.add` when you want to add an error to the model.

Answer (score 2):

`has_many :treatments` in Category and `belongs_to :category` in Treatment means that Treatment can only have one category.

You need to make validation on updates only (creation of new and update). You could write sth like that:

```
before_save :validate_based_on_category
```

and implement your custom validation in method:

```
private
  def validate_based_on_category
    #your validation
  end
```

it's also good to have it as private method

Comment: Would it be possivle with jquery or javascript to make the validation directly when the category is updatet?

Comment: there are two types of updates. on client side - then javascript can work, on server side then validation errors will be passed in `flash` and you'll have: 
`<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <%= content_tag(:div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}") %>
    <% end %>`
for every message in flash. Flash can have success,notice,error message types